# Unable to install wine on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: wine

I am a new user of Linux, and while trying to install "wine" on Ubuntu 16.04, I encountered the following problem:

```
myname@my-computer:~$ sudo apt-get install winehq-staging
[sudo] password for myname:  

E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

What could the problem be?

Comment: Do you have another software management tool open, such as the Ubuntu software center, or Synaptic ? Try restarting your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to remove lock?

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

And install what you want.